# Elapsed time on a timer?

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

I have a really simple bit of code I use to test the response from proxy servers, I want to be able to start a timer and stop it and get the elapsed time it took for those to happen. However, I don't believe the code I have below is what I'm looking for.

```
var proxyStopWatch = new Timer();
proxyStopWatch.Start();

string[] splitProxy = ProxyList[i].Split('|');
string testResults = HTMLProcessor.HTMLProcessing.HTMLResults("http://www.google.com", splitProxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(splitProxy[1]), true, out testResults);

ProxyListResults.Add(ProxyList+"|"+proxyStopWatch.Interval.ToString());
proxyStopWatch.Stop();
```

Comment: It is not, use the Stopwatch class.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To just get elapsed time, the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class will probably be easier to use.

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

// do stuff

stopWatch.Stop();
long duration = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score 14):

Here is an example that uses the stopwatch from System.Diagnostics namespace:

```
var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();

Thread.Sleep(10000);
stopWatch.Stop();

// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
var ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

// Format and display the TimeSpan value.
string elapsedTime = $"{ts.Hours}:{ts.Minutes}:{ts.Seconds}.{ts.Milliseconds / 10}";
    
Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right. I don't think that's what you are looking for. You can simply do:

```
var start = DateTime.Now;
string[] splitProxy = ProxyList[i].Split('|');

string testResults 
     = HTMLProcessor.HTMLProcessing.HTMLResults("http://www.google.com", 
     splitProxy[0], Convert.ToInt32(splitProxy[1]), true, out testResults);
ProxyListResults.Add(ProxyList+"|"+proxyStopWatch.Interval.ToString());

Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed in milliseconds was: " + 
    (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
```